# Assign attr to top level uls

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm pretty new to jquery and I have what is likely a very simple problem.

I'm trying to implement a flyout menu for navigation on a new site, and because of the limitations put on me by my CMS, I'm unable to add classes to the `<ul>`'s to which the flyout functionality will be applied.

For example:

Change this:

```
<div class="SideCategoryListClassic">
<ul **class="fancynav"**>
    <li class=""><a href="http://blah.com/categories/product/">Product</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="LastChild">
                 <a href="http://blah.com/categories/product/Accessories/">Accessories</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul **class="fancynav"**>
    <li class=""><a href="http://blah.com/categories/product/">Product</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="LastChild">
                 <a href="http://blah.com/categories/product/Accessories/">Accessories</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

To this:

```
<div class="SideCategoryListClassic">
<ul>
    <li class=""><a href="http://blah.com/categories/product/">Product</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="LastChild">
                 <a href="http://blah.com/categories/product/Accessories/">Accessories</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li class=""><a href="http://blah.com/categories/product/">Product</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="LastChild">
                 <a href="http://blah.com/categories/product/Accessories/">Accessories</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Again, sure it's simple but I'm not sure how to only grab those top level `<ul>`'s without getting the ones nested within them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".SideCategoryListClassic > ul")
```

This gets only `ul`s that are direct children of `.SideCategoryListClassic`

Comment: so it would be $(".SideCategoryListClassic > ul").addClass('fancyNav')?

Comment: Thanks.  Works perfectly.  now I know about the `>`operator in this context.  And thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like the following ...

```
$(".SideCategoryListClassic").children("ul").addClass("myClass");
```

the `children("ul")` bit will only get the top level `<ul>` tags

Comment: There's no reason to use `each` here, simply replace the `each` with the `addClass` call.